# Entity FrameWork version 6 does not update Stored Procedure

Tags: entity-framework

I am using an stored procedure with Entity Framework version 6.  I added a new column to my query and then updated the edmx model from the database but do not see the new column.

Has anyone had this problem and how can I get the new column to be included?

Comment: I don't know about version 6 but in the past EF was notorious with not 'updating' the model.  'Updating' for me used to be delete, re add with tables, foreign keys, views and procs.  EF has weird issues with updating it's model even up to EF 6.1.3.  I have not tried it but you could give Entity Core a chance which is supposed to be the new thing that is platform agnostic.

Comment: Try to access Model Browser in yout edmx. In "Tables / views" and "Entity Types" sections remove your table and then add it one more time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to bcesars suggestion I deleted the stored procedure from the data model and added it back and the new column was included in the new model.

Thanks again